# How to unit test addTodo in redux app?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am trying this example :

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todomvc

Based in this solution I have created a unit test that looks like this:

```
it('should call addTodo if length of text is greater than 0', () => {

    const props = {
      addTodo: jest.fn()
    }

    let cb = shallow(<Header {...props} />)

    expect(props.addTodo).not.toBeCalled()

    cb.find('TodoTextInput').simulate("onSave",{text:"fsdhsd"});

    //error starts here:
    expect(props.addTodo).toBeCalled()


  });
```

The result of this one is :
FAIL  src/components/NewHeaderTest.spec.js
  ●

```
Header enzyme style › should call addTodo if length of text is greater than 0

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called.

    at Object.it (src/components/NewHeaderTest.spec.js:46:27)
```

This is part of the component:

```
handleSave = text => {
    console.log('handlesave');
    if (text.length > 0) {
      this.props.addTodo(text);
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <TodoTextInput onSave={this.handleSave}>
        </TodoTextInput>
      </header>)
  }
```

How can I fix the unittest or how to pass in an argument for the simulate statement:    cb.find('TodoTextInput').simulate("onSave",{text:"fsdhsd"});

Comment: What is the result of the unit test if you remove the text.length check?

Comment: it is the same error message

Comment: Try `cb.find('TodoTextInput').simulate("save",{text:"fsdhsd"});` ?